# How to change all pixels in Gimp that are not one of two colors to white?

Tags: gimp, transparency, color-conversion

I was trying to submit an app to the Windows Phone app store. Here all pixels need to be white (#FFFFFF) or transparant (#FF####).

I had a black logo on a white background. To make the background transparant and the foreground white I used Gimp. First I made the background transparant using the magic wand and changing color to alpha. Then I inverted the remaining colors. Unfortunately the images did not get accepted in the Windows Phone app store because not all pixels were white or transparant.

How can non-white or transparant pixels in Gimp be converted to white?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you need the GIF format? PNG would allow smooth edges with transparency.

To edit the output colors you should first set your color mode to Indexed (`Image > Mode > Indexed`). For the conversion select `Use black and white (1-bit) palette`

Then you can edit the color table (`Window > Dockable Dialogues > Colormap`). Just doubleclick the black color and set it to white.

Edit: For a PNG you can use Colorize (`Colors > Colorize`) where you can set `Lightness` to `+100` to make everything white. This will keep transparency intact.

Comment: Hi AAGD, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: The lightness trick did work perfectly for my PNG icon, didn't think about that one!

Comment: `Lightness`adjustment is the quick and easy way for PNG - thanks!

Comment: `Lightness` worked for me too! I also had to make sure that the entire canvas was selected.